# Image not spreading on the whole face

Tags: uv

I am learning UV mapping, trying to map an image on one side of a cube but it does not spread properly on the whole face.. Here is what I get:

[image: The final result I get]

[image]

I know this can be done simply by applying materials to the specified sides but I want to apply different images in future. Can anyone tell me what is going on? I want to color the central part only, not the boundary.

Thanks

Comment: I have a feeling that you have a bevel modifier which is messing this up. If you *do* have a bevel modifier, make sure the limit method is set to *Angle*.

Comment: bevel and subsurface division. I wanted to give this curved look around the edges.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the *limit method* on the bevel modifier is set to *angle*, so that only the edges between faces with very different normals are beveled:

[image]

If you have the limit method set to *none*, the edges on the flat parts of the cube will be beveled (which creates extra geometry without changing the shape), and the UVs are not interpolated correctly:

[image]